# WinActivate on window by process name?

Tags: autohotkey

Simply put, I want Ctrl+Alt+T to activate the Windows Terminal window. Previously I've used this:

```
^!T::
    if WinExist("Windows PowerShell")
        WinActivate
    else
        Run, wt
Return
```

But this doesn't cut it anymore, because the Windows Terminal changes its title when I am using Posh Git.

So I need to activate the window on whatever window that has the process name "WindowsTerminal.exe".

I've tried this but for some reason it does not recognize the correct window:

```
^!T::
    if WinExist(ahk_exe "WindowsTerminal.exe")
        WinActivate
    else
        Run, wt
Return
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for invoking [WinExist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm) with the name of a process/ exe is incorrect

Instead of:

```
if WinExist(ahk_exe "WindowsTerminal.exe")
```

You need to also include the `ahk_exe` part of it within the quotation marks.

So like this:

```
if WinExist("ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe")
```

---

Final Code:

```
^!T::
    if WinExist("ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe")
        WinActivate
    else
        Run, wt
Return
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I didn't know about https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#LastFoundWindow

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
^!T::
    _WindowId = -1
    WinGet _Windows, List
    Loop %_Windows%
    {
        _Id := _Windows%A_Index%
        WinGet, _PName , ProcessName, ahk_id %_Id%
        if (_PName == "WindowsTerminal.exe")
        {
            _WindowId = %_Id%
            break
        }
    }
    if (_WindowId != -1)
    {
        WinActivate, ahk_id %_WindowId%
    } else
    {
        Run, wt
    }
Return
```

There's probably a shorter way to do this with AHK but I can't be bothered with that gross syntax anymore.

Comment: Yes there is a shorter way using winexist instead of looping with winget see accepted answer